Problem renaming index value in pandas multiindex series
Please consider this dataframe:
temp = pd.DataFrame({'has_exclamation': {('automotive', 0.0): 99.1814132659203,
  ('automotive', np.nan): 0.8185867340796917,
  ('beauty_spa', 0.0): 99.8,
  ('beauty_spa', np.nan): 0.15384615384615385,
  ('beauty_spa', 1.0): 0.04615384615384615},
 'has_exclamation_end': {('automotive', 0.0): 99.1814132659203,
  ('automotive', np.nan): 0.8185867340796917,
  ('beauty_spa', 0.0): 99.83846153846154,
  ('beauty_spa', np.nan): 0.15384615384615385,
  ('beauty_spa', 1.0): 0.007692307692307693},
 'has_all_cap': {('automotive', 0.0): 98.88046226074395,
  ('automotive', np.nan): 0.8185867340796917,
  ('beauty_spa', 0.0): 99.56153846153846,
  ('beauty_spa', np.nan): 0.15384615384615385,
  ('beauty_spa', 1.0): 0.28461538461538466}})

temp:

To replace the NaNs with 'Missing' in the index, why does this not work?
temp.rename(index={np.nan: 'Missing'}, level =1)


The issue is that NaN is not correctly matched with np.nan (a NaN is not equal to itself).
You could proceed in two step by first converting to string:
temp.rename(str).rename({'nan': 'Missing'})

Or convert the Index to_frame:
temp.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(temp.index.to_frame().fillna('Missing'),
                                      names=temp.index.names
                                     )

Output:
                    has_exclamation  has_exclamation_end  has_all_cap
automotive 0.0            99.181413            99.181413    98.880462
           Missing              NaN                  NaN          NaN
beauty_spa 0.0            99.800000            99.838462    99.561538
           Missing              NaN                  NaN          NaN
           1.0             0.046154             0.007692     0.284615



create a new list of tuples new_index

Convert the new_index to multi-index and assign to the dataframe.
 new_index = [(x[0], 'Missing' if pd.isna(x[1]) else x[1]) for x in  temp.index]

 temp.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_index)



Output
                has_exclamation  has_exclamation_end  has_all_cap
automotive 0.0            99.181413            99.181413    98.880462
           Missing              NaN                  NaN          NaN
beauty_spa 0.0            99.800000            99.838462    99.561538
           Missing              NaN                  NaN          NaN
           1.0             0.046154             0.007692     0.284615

